# Download pdf file slim php

Tags: php, rest, pdf, download, slim

I've the following service to download a pdf file:

```
$app->options('/docDownload',function(){}); // This one just so you can accept OPTIONS
$app->get('/docDownload', function () use ($app){

    $path = "working.pdf";
    $res = $app->response();
    $res['Content-Description'] = 'File Transfer';
    $res['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream';
    $res['Content-Disposition'] ='attachment; filename=' . basename($path);
    $res['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'binary';
    $res['Expires'] = '0';
    $res['Cache-Control'] = 'must-revalidate';
    $res['Pragma'] = 'public';
    $res['Content-Length'] = filesize($path);
    readfile($path);
});
```

However when i run the service, i got the following response:

> ```
> %PDF-1.5
> ```
>
> %����
>   1 0 obj
>   <>>>
>   endobj
>   2 0 obj
>   <>
>   endobj
>   3 0 obj
>   <>/ExtGState<>/ProcSet[/PDF
>   /Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 595.32 841.92] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>>
>   endobj
>   4 0 obj
>   <>
>   stream
>   x���Kk�0����9J�����`|�� �@����J�C
>   M!��$��bA,�ш]T�h�j��V0]���r���0��8R0L.F����70�3�}�8\�08L�V�Q��+�')��g��U;��V
>   ��8�o�����o��Ip�I}�W_�r}��N'mգU��g>Ö�Ӎ���n>�D��.�-����<H`��ABC\ǐ'�=��ٻXwc�z��wx�
>   endstream
>   endobj
>   5 0 obj
>   <>
>   endobj
>   6 0 obj
>   <>
>   endobj
>   7 0 obj
>   <>
>   endobj
>   8 0 obj
>   .....

To open the pdf i need to click with the second mouse button on the response link:

[WS url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfIny.png)

and select open in a new tab to open the pdf file, it seems as you are running the service two times to get the pdf file once.

I would like to open automatically the pdf file on each request to the WS.

This means every time you request the WS, this should return the pdf file directly opened in the screen.

Could someone help me fixing it?

Tks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to use the correct MIME type, try this

`$res['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf';`

Comment: I already tried with the correct MIME type, and doesn't work at same.

Comment: Nobody has an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Is there a change instead retrieving a binary response document, retrieve a pdf document? tks

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to not download the file using an AJAX call (it seems that you're using this way).
This is how your page download page would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var PDF_DOWNLOAD_URL = "{{ urlFor('PDFDownload') }}";
$(function(){
    //Your old way
    $("button.download-file").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: PDF_DOWNLOAD_URL,
            headers: { 'x-my-custom-header': 'some value' },
            success: function(data){
                console.log("Data received:", data);
            }
        });
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" class="download-file">Download the document</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Your route should define a name in this way:

```
$app->get('/docDownload', function () use ($app){
    $path = "working.pdf";
    $res = $app->response();
    $res['Content-Description'] = 'File Transfer';
    $res['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    $res['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'binary';
    $res['Expires'] = '0';
    $res['Cache-Control'] = 'must-revalidate';
    $res['Pragma'] = 'public';
    $fileData = file_get_contents($path);
    $base64 = base64_encode($fileData);
    $response = array();
    $response['pdf'] = $base64;
    $response['customKey'] = "My Custom Value";
    echo json_encode($response);
})->name("PDFDownload");
```

Comment: Well! On this way works, but i need to stream the file as binary and after re-build the pdf on the jquery/javascript side! The final service will return a json object with the binary information inside and other information.

Comment: And I have authentication by headers parameters, and on your solution when you simulate to open a new tab to download the documents, you have no access to the headers data!

Comment: What do you mean with 'The final service will return a json object with the binary information inside and other information.'? Please edit your question with all details about your input and your expected output. Thanks

Comment: for know i'm trying this phase, where i want to convert the binary to pdf file again. But in the future i will send the binary data into an array position! That's why i'm telling you the above approach doesn't work with json objects!